# Byte masking in java

Tags: java, byte, masking

There's something I'm struggling to understand, I have this piece of code :

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static int readByte(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}

public static short readShort(byte[] b) {
    return (short)(readByte(b[0]) | readByte(b[1]) << 8);
}

 public static void main(String []args){
    byte[] b = {(byte)0x94, 0x00};
    System.out.println(readShort(b));

 }
}
```

Now the result returned is 148, but I don't understand why if I remove the masking "& 0xFF", the result will change, if you're reading 1 byte at a time the masking of 0xFF doesn't suppose to affect the byte (that's what I know atleast), a friend of mine tried to explain me this and he said it's related to the byte "0x94" being unsigned and the casting going on in the readByte method but I couldn't understand it and I'm really having hard time to understand why you need the masking to read the byte properly, thanks in advance for anyone trying to help me !

Comment: Check out my post on this http://doridori.github.io/Java-Bitshifting-Bytes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte is signed data.  So 0x94 is -108.  When you return it as an int, you return -108 expanded to 4  bytes, which is NOT 0x94 (its FFFFFF94).  That obviously screws up your later ORing.  The mask fixes it because the byte 0x94 is converted to an int before ANDing it with 0xFF, so the AND will drop those extra 1s from the negative expansion.

Comment: I know that because you return it as an int you add 3 more bytes to the original one but I still dont understand something and Im not sure what, I'll try to explain it how I SEE IT step by step and maybe you could figure what I dont understand, say you have this byte 0x94 in binary its 10010100 so you expand it by 3 more bytes it becomes 00000000 00000000 00000000 10010100 so now you get this in binary now after masking you'll get 10010100 and when you return it you'll get 148 in decimal, now without the masking you return 00000000 00000000 00000000 10010100 in binary which is STILL 148 in dec

Comment: It doesn't expand with all 0 bytes.  It *sign expands*.  Negative numbers expand with all 1s and positive numbers expand with all 0s.  Since 0x94 as a byte is actually negative it expands to FFFFFF94, not 00000094.  That's what you're missing.

Comment: ok so I get 11111111 11111111 11111111 01101100 (last byte = positive 108) and the second int we get is 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 and when we ORing them we get the first integer and after casting to short we get 11111111 01101100 which is 65388 so how does it prints -108 again ? sorry I must hard to explain to me I always find it hard to understand bitwise operation well and all that related stuff :|

Comment: So readByte without the mask returns FFFFFF94 for index 0 and FFFFFF00 for index 1.  THen you shift the second and OR them together, which is FFFFFF94 | FFFF0000 = FFFFFF94.  YOu then cast it to a short, which truncates it (keeping the sign) to FF94.  FF94 is -108.  So that's why that happens.  The rule to take away-  in Java you always need to mask before type converting.

Comment: okay thanks but can I know how you convert hex to signed int, because all calculator I use say immediately that 94 in hex is 148 in dec so how does the conversion to signed dec work ?

Comment: Look at the MSB (most significant bit) based on the size of the variable.  If its a 1, the number is negative.  If its a 0, positive.  This works on everything except floats or doubles.  You may also want to read up on how negative numbers work in binary-  its called Two's Complement arithmetic-   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: so its inverting all bits and adding + 1 to get the negative / if u di it in decimal its like getting the unsigned value and subtract from it the highest value possible to be held by the data type say short then subtract 65536 ?

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent, assuming the number is negative.